# Sum elements of a list between zeros in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 9, 45, 3, 0, 1, 7]
```

And I need the sum of the elements between the `0`s in a new list.
I tried

```
lst1 = []
summ = 0
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    if elem != 0:
        summ = summ + elem
    else:
        lst1.append(summ)
        lst1.append(elem)
        summ = 0
```

but it returns `[11, 0, 0, 0, 57, 0]`, while I expect 
`[11, 0, 0, 57, 0, 8]`

Comment: What is your expected output.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych `[11, 0, 0, 57, 0, 8]`

Comment: What are you trying to do? What were your expectations? This code work as written.

Comment: add an extra `lst1.append(summ)` outside the loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to this with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a *list comprehension*. The grouping is done by checking if an element is zero, and if not zero, all items in the group are summed:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 9, 45, 3, 0, 1, 7]
f = lambda x: x==0
result = [i for k, g in groupby(lst, f) for i in (g if k else (sum(g),))]
print(result)
# [11, 0, 0, 57, 0, 8]
```

And of course, if items in your list are only numbers (to avoid generalising and introducing ambuigities), the `lambda` can be replaced with `bool`:

```
result = [i for k, g in groupby(lst, bool) for i in ((sum(g),) if k else g)]
```

Comment: It is much better now :)

Comment: You can get rid of that lambda: `[i for k, g in groupby(lst, bool) for i in ((sum(g),) if k else g)]`

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the head up

Comment: @PM2Ring Had to pull out the `lambda` to make it more readable

Answer (score 2):

you are appending extra summ when its 0, and missing 1 summ at the end

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 9, 45, 3, 0, 1, 7]
lst1 = []
summ = 0
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    if elem != 0:
        summ = summ + elem
    else:
        if summ:
            lst1.append(summ)
        lst1.append(elem)
        summ = 0

if summ:
    lst1.append(summ)
# lst1 = [11, 0, 0, 57, 0, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra `lst1.append(summ)`  after the loop

```
lst1 = []
summ = 0
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    if elem != 0:
        summ = summ + elem
    else:
        if summ:
            lst1.append(summ)
        lst1.append(elem)
        summ = 0
lst1.append(summ)
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output: `[11, 0, 0, 57, 0, 8]`

Comment: Yes, but you wanted `[11, 0, 0, 57, 0, 8]`

Comment: Also, it doesn't handle when `lst` ends in zero. See Skycc's answer.

Comment: That's better, but it still doesn't handle when `lst` ends in zero.