# Sum elements of a vector beween zeros in R

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have a vector with zeros and positives numbers. I would simply like to sum the numbers that are **between** the zeros.

A simple example:

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,23,24,54,12,1,23,0,0,0,0,1,23,56,76,0,1,13)
```

That is, I want to sum the elements `1,23,24,54,12,1,23` , `1,23,56,76` and `1,13`.

My desired output would therefore be: 
`138`, `156` and `14`.

I found this really similar question but it is on Python:
[Sum elements of a list between zeros in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787229/sum-elements-of-a-list-between-zeros-in-python)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `tapply`, creating groups with `cumsum` and take `sum` of each group.

```
new_x <- tapply(x, cumsum(x == 0), sum)
new_x

#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
#  0   0   0   0 138   0   0   0 156  14
```

Since all numbers are positive we can ignore the ones with 0 and filter the one which has value greater than 0.

```
new_x[new_x > 0]
#  5   9  10 
#138 156  14
```

---

We can also follow the same logic with `sapply` and `split`

```
sapply(split(x, cumsum(x==0)), sum)
```

Comment: That split method looks weird. I bet `rle` can be used to split it in a better manner (I have no time to do it though)

Comment: @Sotos what do you mean by weird? It actually gives me the same output as `tapply`

Comment: No no, the output is correct. The way of the split is weird. ([0], [0], [0], ... [0, 23, ...])...whereas I mean that `rle` can be used to split it like [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 23, 24, ...]

Comment: [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968119/split-vector-separated-by-n-zeros-into-different-group)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,23,24,54,12,1,23,0,0,0,0,1,23,56,76,0,1,13)
s <- tapply(x, rleidv(x==0), sum)
s[s!=0]
# > s[s!=0]
#   2   4   6 
# 138 156  14
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very compact, but also does it. Use `which` and `diff` to locate positions in `x` where value changed from non-zero to zero. Use that info to sum relevant sub-vectors.

```
z <- which(x!=0)[diff(which(x!=0))>1] # 12 20
z <- c(1, z, length(x))+1 # 2 13 21 24
for(i in 1:(length(z)-1)){ print(sum(x[z[i]:z[i+1]], na.rm=T)) }

[1] 138
[1] 156
[1] 14
```

Comment: `sapply(1:(length(z)-1), function(i) sum(x[z[i]:z[i+1]], na.rm=TRUE))` to get a vector result